# Facebook pixel seems to works with img but not with js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

I'm new to Facebook Pixel, so I might miss something...
I've dynamically implemented the code in my header (WordPress website), and here is what's generated on the homepage for example:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '--CORRECT_FB_PIXEL_ID--');
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
        content_type: 'page',
        content_ids: ['2'],
        content_name: 'Home'
    });
</script>
<noscript>
    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=--CORRECT_FB_PIXEL_ID--&ev=ViewContent&cd[content_name]=Home&cd[content_type]=page&cd[content_ids]=2&noscript=1" height="1" width="1" style="display:none"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I've checked the Facebook Pixel ID, and it's correct.
If I use the Chrome extension "Facebook Pixel Helper", I see 2 calls, one is correct (the one made by the image), and the other is not (the JS call).

[image: Facebook Pixel error]

Any idea why the JS call fails?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Matt

--- EDIT ---

Here is the information about the "successful" pixel:
[image: Successful Pixel]

Comment: Why does the Image Code even get called when it's inside <noscript>?

Comment: I find it weird, as there is plenty of JS in this page... Could it be a fallback for the JS part? (from what I know of the noscrit tag, I would say no, but I'm open to any explanation!...)

Comment: maybe try both seperatly to make sure the js part really doesn't work

Comment: _“one is correct (the one made by the image)”_ - are you sure that was send by the image? (I’d try and use a different content id or name for the image, for testing.)

Comment: CBroe, yes, if I expand the information about Pixel Code I see that it comes from the image. I've edited my question and added a screen capture of the "successful" pixel.

Comment: OK, I just realized that on my homepage, I do have another Facebook JS call to display a Facebook feed. So I browsed to an inner page, where this is the only FB JS call, and I still have the same behavior.

Strange thing now: if I remove the <noscript> part, it works. The FB pixel is loaded through JS.
If I remove the <script> part, just leaving the <noscript> part, it doesn't work.
COuld it be the normal behavior that when both script and noscript tags are present, it works for one and not for the other?

Comment: Not, that is not normal behavior. The image/noscript combo is for clients that don’t have JS enabled - it is supposed to be the fallback for this situation, but not an exclusive alternative.